# refer an precompiled asset in javascript + rails4

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a rails 4 application in which I use gmapjs to display a map with markers. The detailed data for each marker is retrieved by making an ajax on the mouseover event. I use infoWindow to display the details. I have to display the application logo in each infoWindow.

the infowindow code is as:

```
a.infoWindow.setContent('<div id="hover'+item.id+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">'+
  '<img src="'+logo_path+'" class="Image">' + 
  '<div class="cmp_name">' +
  data.name +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
  '<img src="'+window.location.href+'/assets/logo_sm.png" class="pull-right">'
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

here the logo_path is "window.location.href + data.logo.url". I have to display the image named 'logo_sm.png'. It works in development but fails in production because during asset precompilation, its renamed.

What would be the ideal approach to refer an image thats going to be precompiled in the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are creating the javascript in your assets (say in maps.js)

You should just be able to use erb, ie `maps.js.erb`  and then build out you string using `image_url` || `image_path`  such as.

```
a.infoWindow.setContent('<div id="hover'+item.id+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">'+
  '<img src="'+logo_path+'" class="Image">' + 
  '<div class="cmp_name">' +
  data.name +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
  '<img src="<%= image_url('logo_sm.png')%>" class="pull-right">'
  '</div>' +
  '</div>'
);
```

Comment: I changed the file name to load_map.js to load_map.js.haml. Getting Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'load_map'
  (in /home/username/freelance/project/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:19)

Comment: HAML is really aimed at HTML, I would try using ERB, since I know that works.  how are you referencing it from your application.js file

Comment: i m using //= require load_map to load the js file in application.js

Comment: could you try the `.erb` version.  Since I am not sure haml gets added to the load paths.